# Branch curve and multi-tangent lines to a surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider a generic surface $X \subset \mathbb{P}^3$, say of degree $d \geq 4$. I am interested in studying the family of multi-tangent lines to this surface. By multi-tangent I mean either bitangent lines or asymptotic tangent lines. To be more precise:

Take a line $l \in \mathbb{G}(1,3)$ not on $X$ (even if with these hypotheses $X$ has no lines on it - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549882/general-surface-no-lines)).
Then I can consider the intersection divisor $l_X := n_1x_1 + \cdots + n_hx_h$ where $X_i \in l \cap X$, where $\sum n_i = d$.
The line $l$ is tangent to $X$ if there is an $n_i \geq 2$, is asymptotic tangent to $X$ if there is an $n_i \geq 3$ and it is bitangent if there are $x_i \neq x_j$ such that $n_i, n_j \geq 2$.

**Question**: consider a generic point $p \in \mathbb{P}^3$ (then not belonging to $X$). Is it there a multi-tangent line $l$ passing through $p$?

(Notice that this is true if one consider tangent lines, and it comes from the fact that there exists a tangent plane to $X$ passing through $p$).

**The branch curve of projections**
My question is very related to the study of the branch locus $B$ of the projection of $X$ from the point $p$. My main reference here is this article of [Ciliberto and Flamini](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.0467v2.pdf), where they proved that, while the smooth points of $B$ correspond to simply tangent lines to $X$ passing trough $p$, the singular points of $B$ corresponds exactly to a multi-tangent line passing through $p$ (even better: cusps corresponds to asymptotic lines, simple nodes to bitangents, ...). I know that $B$ is not too singular (it is basically the content of [Section 3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.0467v2.pdf)), but unfortunately I don't see if I have to expect such a $B$ to be singular or not for the generic $X$. Thus I have this alternative question which answer is the same of my first one

**Alternative question**: Consider as before the branch locus $B$ of the projection of a generic $X$ from a generic point $p$. Is $B$ singular?

Note that, even I specified $d \geq 4$, the answer is true for a generic cubic surface (hence smooth, hence... https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249924/branch-locus-of-projection-of-cubic-surface)

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It seems like a very reasonable question.

Comment: Ok, maybe the article I pointed out [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/249924/branch-locus-of-projection-of-cubic-surface) contains the solution. Actually the answer of Felipe Voloch does not depends on the degree, one can work out the math for a surface of degree $d$ finding that the number of singular points is always positive for $d \geq 3$.